# Redirect www to non www with subfolder and links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

Ok, so i want to redirect all www to non www link,

I want to redirect www.example.com to example.com, and i can do that too using this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But when someone try to access www.example.com/example, that redirects the site to example.com,

I want a code that can redirect www.example.com/example or any subfolder to example.com/example or any subfolder.

Kinda like a wildcard entry, how to do that?

Also if possible force ssl on it too.

Thank You.

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. Try clearing your browser cache

Comment: Tried in incognito too, doenst work.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly:

www.example.com/dir/anypage.html to example.com/dir/anypage.html (same page)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

OR Use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subfoldername/$1 [R=301,L]
```

-------- Alternative---------

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /subfolder/index.php [L]
```

To force SSL:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Doesn't work, same as before, /subfolder doesnt get redirected. it redirects to main page only.

Comment: Hey @Harsh, try this: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subfoldername/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: i want is to be dynamic, not only for a single subfolder, but for all.

Comment: @Harsh, Check Alternative in answer. If that does not work, after that, I'm thinking you will need to do it for each subfolder you have (If there is not too many).

Comment: alternative is for specific folder right? not for all?

Comment: @Harsh, Yes, so it is for the specific subfolder and then anything within that subfolder. So you would need to do it for each subfolder.

Comment: what about folders under subfolder?